# Google Apps Script - TypeError: Cannot read property "1" from null

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, google-apps-script, null

I put together a Google Apps Script to pull some data from my emails and insert it into a spreadsheet. The script is actually running great and inserting the data fine, but I keep getting the following error in my log:

`TypeError: Cannot read property "1" from null. (line 46, file "Code")`

[According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec#Return_value), the `exec` method returns an array with "the matched text as the first item, and then one item for each capturing parenthesis that matched containing the text that was captured." Since I want the value within the parenthesis of my regex, rather than the entire matched text, I'm using `[1]`.

Here's the function in question:

```
function getEmails() {
  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("CapitalOne Transaction");
  var threads = label.getThreads(); // Get threads of label above
  for (var i in threads) {
    var messages = threads[i].getMessages();
    for (var j in messages) {
      if ( messages[j].isUnread() ) {
        var emailBody = messages[j].getPlainBody();
        Logger.log("Email body: " + emailBody);

        // Get account number
        const regExpAcct = /Account ending in (\d{4})/g;
        var message_account = regExpAcct.exec(emailBody);
        if(message_account){ Logger.log("Email message accnt: " + message_account[1]); }

        // Get date of transaction
        var regExpDate = /we're notifying you that on (...+), at/g;
        var message_date = regExpDate.exec(emailBody);
        if(message_date){ Logger.log("Email message date: " + message_date[1]); }

        // Get vendor name
        var regExpVendor = /, at (...+),/g;
        var message_vendor = regExpVendor.exec(emailBody);
        if(message_vendor){ Logger.log("Email message vendor: " + message_vendor[1]); }

        // Get transaction amount
        const regExpAmount = /purchase in the amount of \$(\S+) was/g;
        var message_amount = regExpAmount.exec(emailBody);
        if(message_amount){ Logger.log("Email message amount: " + message_amount[1]); }

        addDataToSpreadsheet( message_date[1], message_account[1], message_vendor[1], message_amount[1] );
        messages[j].markRead();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The line(46) in question is this one: `addDataToSpreadsheet( message_date[1], message_account[1], message_vendor[1], message_amount[1] );`

Which calls this function:

```
function addDataToSpreadsheet( date, account, vendor, amount ) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.appendRow( [date, account, vendor, amount] );
}
```

My `Logger.log`s after each regex all output the variables fine, and like I said, the data is being input into the spreadsheet perfectly with the function above, but I still get the error every time the `getEmails()` function runs.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is clear that one of the regexps does not match and when you try accessing the Group 1 value of such a match, you get an exception. I suggest assigning those values to separate variables and use them later to pass to `addDataToSpreadsheet` function:

```
var emailBody = messages[j].getPlainBody();
Logger.log("Email body: " + emailBody);
var message_account = "", message_date = "", message_vendor = "", message_amount = "";

// Get account number
const regExpAcct = /Account ending in (\d{4})/;
var message_account_m = regExpAcct.exec(emailBody);
if(message_account_m){ message_account = message_account_m[1]; Logger.log("Email message accnt: " + message_account); }
// Get date of transaction
var regExpDate = /we're notifying you that on (...+), at/;
var message_date_m = regExpDate.exec(emailBody);
if(message_date_m){ message_date = message_date_m[1]; Logger.log("Email message date: " + message_date); }

// Get vendor name
var regExpVendor = /, at (...+),/;
var message_vendor_m = regExpVendor.exec(emailBody);
if(message_vendor_m){ message_vendor = message_vendor_m[1]; Logger.log("Email message vendor: " + message_vendor); }

// Get transaction amount
const regExpAmount = /purchase in the amount of \$(\S+) was/;
var message_amount_m = regExpAmount.exec(emailBody);
if(message_amount_m){ message_amount = message_amount_m[1]; Logger.log("Email message amount: " + message_amount); }

addDataToSpreadsheet( message_date, message_account, message_vendor, message_amount);
messages[j].markRead();
```

Now, all the four variables - `message_account`,  `message_date`, `message_vendor`  and `message_amount` - are assigned an empty string. Even if a regex fails, and a Group 1 value is not assigned to any of them, when they are referred later in the code, they will cause no errors upon invoking as they are assigned some value.

Note that since you are not iterating over the matches, `/g` modifier is unnecessary.

Comment: Great. Worked like a charm. No error after doing this.

Comment: Can you explain(maybe add to your answer for future Googlers) why simply putting the `message_amount_m[1]` into it's own separate variable(`message_amount`) to use in `addDataToSpreadsheet()` works instead of `addDataToSpreadsheet( message_date_m[1], message_account_m[1], message_vendor_m[1], message_amount_m[1]);`? I was getting the correct values from each of the regex, so they were matching fine.

Comment: @dmoz I added some more explanation.

Comment: I think it is some behavior in JS engine, that occurring failure. As computer makes logic based on binary numbers, and we wrote our code in english like language, some time multiply two float gives unexpected results, we called it approximate not exact result, to overcome we do change our logic accordingly, here is similar situation, so our friend finds a solution to that, but exactly problem will oily noticed if you have proper exception or error handling.

Comment: Probably JS engine unable to detect the type of array element by index. And by using another variable it converts them into primitive type, array and objects in JavaScript are basically some pointer, those are considered as a complex objects.